# Fit all components on one row

Tags: react-native, layout

How can I fit all components on one row?
With the current code this is what's displaying (note the Add text is outside the viewport): 
[image: Current output]

And this is the code

```js
return (
  <View style={styles.header}>
    <View style={styles.headerLeft}>
      <Text style={styles.back}>❮</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Header text that is going to wrap</Text>
    </View>

    <View>
      <Text style={styles.add}>Add</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

And here are the styles:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    marginTop: '15%',
    marginHorizontal: '5%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  headerLeft: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  back: {
    fontSize: 18,     
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 26,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingHorizontal: 20
  },
  add: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'blue'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a view for the text that is going to wrap. After adding a view, you need to add a width to the style of the view. This will ensure that the text will stay within that width. Here is the edited code: -

```
return (
  <View style={styles.header}>
    <View style={styles.headerLeft}>
      <Text style={styles.back}>❮</Text>
      <View style={styles.textView}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Header text that is going to wrap</Text>
      </View>
      
    </View>

    <View>
      <Text style={styles.add}>Add</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Styles will be: -

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    marginTop: '15%',
    marginHorizontal: '5%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  headerLeft: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  back: {
    fontSize: 18,     
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 26,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingHorizontal: 20, 
  },
  add: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'blue'
  },
  textView: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.7,
  },
});
```

You can change the width of the text by replacing 0.7 with some other multiple